# Regex group matching not giving expected results

Tags: regex

I have having little trouble getting the required match.

```
string1 ="lanet fit/club fees 123-456-7150 1935006123456 abcd avcbfg"
string2 ="ABC*lanet Fitness       308-3207001  NX"

regex=^(.*)([(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-.\s][0-9]{3}[-.\s]?[0-9]{4})(.*)$
```

also can be checked here. [regexr.com/5ahru](http://regexr.com/5ahru)

I need group 2 as the phone number `123-456-7150`and `308-3207001` but i am getting `150 1935006` as group 2 for string1.

Any thing which needs to be corrected?

Comment: Make the first `.*` non-greedy, `.*?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/wk8rKM/1)).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. looks like this will work